# Reading according to regex in java

Tags: java, regex, stack-trace

My input is sample.log

```
13 Aug 2013 11:28:30,414 [WebContainer : 6] ERROR - An Error has occured for  com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
13 Aug 2013 11:28:30,414 [WebContainer : 6] ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
 at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.prepareUserContext(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.preexecute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))
  13 Aug 2013 11:28:30,414 [WebContainer : 6] ERROR - An Error has occured for com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
  13 Aug 2013 11:28:30,414 [WebContainer : 6] ERROR - handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.prepareUserContext(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.preexecute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))
```

I just want output each log entry as one event, even entire stack trace as one event.

something like this

```
   13 Aug 2013 11:28:30,414 [WebContainer : 6] ERROR - An Error has occured for  com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.

   13 Aug 2013 11:28:30,414 [WebContainer : 6] ERROR -  handleException():com.marsh.framework.core.exception.MarshException: Your session has timed out.
   at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.prepareUserContext(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
   at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.preexecute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
   at com.marsh.csa.serviceagreement.CSAAbstractStrutsAction.execute(CSAAbstractStrutsAction.java(Compiled Code))
   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java(Compiled Code))
   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java(Inlined Compiled Code))
   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java(Compiled Code))
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java(Compiled Code))
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java(Compiled Code))
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java(Compiled Code))
```

code

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("D:/sample.log"));

    sc.findInLine("(\\S*\\d+\\s\\w+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+\\:\\d+\\:\\d+\\,\\d+)\\S*");

  while (sc.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(sc.nextLine()+"\n");
```

But above code gives each line separately. Grouping entire stacktrace as one event is possible with scanner?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Scanner is the right tool for this job.  Scanner is for breaking a file into tokens using a delimiter and then optionally parsing those tokens.  You seem to be just trying to test if a line of a log file is the start of a log statement or not.  It would make more sense to read the file line by line and test each for whether it starts a log statement or not.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S*\\d+\\s\\w+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+\\:\\d+\\:\\d+\\,\\d+)\\S*");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String inputLine;
String outputLine = null;
while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (outputLine == null) {
        outputLine = inputLine;
    } else if (pattern.matches(inputLine)) {
        System.out.println(outputLine);
        outputLine = inputLine;
    } else {
        outputLine += inputLine;
    }
}
System.out.println(outputLine);
```

Comment: Some dissatisfaction with my answer above made me look at this more carefully. The last bit of your regex, \\S*, is trying to match non-whitespace, but there's clearly whitespace in a stack trace. Also, since you're not compiling your regex pattern as I do, it won't match over line boundaries. Also, you're calling `sc.findInLine` which will only go line by line. And lastly, you'd need to remove the newlines from any stacktrace you find to have it print the way you want.

Comment: Hi David,
I'm trying your code but it is giving me error at else if (pattern.matches(inputLine))  as Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method matches(String, CharSequence) in the type Pattern is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Instead try `pattern.matcher(inputLine).matches()`